# How to roll back to a previous version of Thunderbird

Tags: software-installation, email, thunderbird

The recent release of Thunderbird 115 broke a very useful extension called Full Address Column.  How does one roll back to Thunderbird 102.15.1?

Comment: Thunderbird updates frequently because it shares a lot of code with Firefox web browser. That means that many Firefox vulnerabilities are also Thunderbird vulnerabilities. And web browsers, including Firefox, get a lot of reported vulnerabilities. So don't let your Thunderbird fall too far behind.

Answer (score 6):

1. Remove existing Thunderbird and retain configuration files (email accounts, messages and addresses) `sudo apt remove thunderbird`
2. Download Thunderbird 102.15.1 from [Mozilla Thunderbird Archives](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/102.15.1/)
3. Extract downloaded archive to `/home/user`
4. Save this icon (or similar) to `/home/user/thunderbird-102.15.1/thunderbird/icons`

[image]

5. Using a text editor create a file called `Thunderbird.desktop` as follows and save to `/home/user/.local/share/applications`

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/user/thunderbird-102.15.1/thunderbird/thunderbird
Name=Thunderbird
Comment=Thunderbird
Icon=/home/user/thunderbird-102.15.1/thunderbird/icons/TB.png
```

6. Make file executable by: `chmod +x /home/user/.local/share/applications/Thunderbird.desktop`
7. Locate Thunderbird 102.15.1 using `Activities` or `Super Key`
8. Right click Thunderbird icon and select `Add to Favorites`
9. Launch Thunderbird and decline creating new account.  Select `Tools > Import > Import Another Thunderbird Install > Continue > Import from profile "default" > Continue`
10. Relaunch Thunderbird and install `Full Address Column` extension
11. Go into settings and change updates from "auto" to "ask".  Otherwise TB will update to 115 and you will be back to square 1.

Interesting to see how many people have posted requests for "full address column" to Mozilla and they continue to ignore these requests.

Comment: +1 Saving the icon is a nice detail.

Comment: If Thunderbird is like Firefox, it *may* refuse to use the newer existing profile, any you may have to create a new one. Blessed the man who has backups! ;-)

Comment: True enough!  Although backup profile at least on TB in Ubuntu is limited to 2GB maximum.